# ¿Como usar la API de bing news en php?

Tags: php, api, bing-search

Deseo implementar la `API` de `Bing News` para poder mostrar noticias relacionadas al tema de la página, el problema es que no se como usarla, ya obtuve el código necesario para poder hacer las consultas al servidor, pero no se como usarlo.

En la web de `Microsoft` hay páginas de documentación con respecto a cómo construir los links de las consultas, pero despues de eso no se como elaborar codigo php para manejar los resultados.

Imagino que debe de haber una forma estándar para hacer este tipo de request y almacenarlas en un `JSON`, pero no se como buscarlo, he estado intentando y no doy con la clave.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que has intentado (quitando claves) y los errores con los que te has encontrado.

Comment: Es que la verdad no tengo codigo, ni errores ni nada, no se como proceder a pedir informacion mediante codigo. https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-news-search-api/documentation Eso es lo que trato de implementar pero no veo ejemplos o una documentacion que me diga como usarlo. Por eso pienso que es algo que es común, no se si me explico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes encontrar un ejemplos de como usar la `News Search API - V5` en distintos leguajes ingresando a la [`API Reference`](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf).

### Ejemplo en `PHP`

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components 
// (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
    'q' => 'microsoft',
    'count' => '10',
    'offset' => '0',
    'mkt' => 'en-us',
    'safeSearch' => 'Moderate',
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

Comment: Esta bien amigo, pero de donde saco el archivo Request2.php ?

Comment: @GerardoAGL96, de [aqui](https://github.com/pear/HTTP_Request2)

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya logre que funcionara.